# Java close Connection seem not worked

Tags: java, postgresql, connection

I use `storedProcedure` in `PostgreSQL`, my entire `SQL methods` like this.

```
   private static final String HOP_DATA_GO = "{ ? =  call hop_go() }";
        public String hopData() {
            String result = "false";
            Connection conn = null;
            InitialContext itx = null;
            CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
            try {
                itx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ods = (DataSource) itx.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
                conn = ods.getConnection();
                callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(HOP_DATA_GO);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
                callableStatement.executeUpdate();
                result = callableStatement.getString(1);
            } catch (SQLException exception) {
                Logger.getLogger(HopImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(HopImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            } finally {
                if (callableStatement != null) {
                    try {
                        callableStatement.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HopImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HopImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
  }
```

Every time at the end of method, I close the connection . But , when I checked from DataBase:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database
```

There are a lot of `numbackends` ( `connections` ), and I don't understand where they are come from,why they aren't close, or is that mean close ? 
I try this query

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

This is one row of this `query`

```
backend_start: 2015-10-21 14:43:17.932223+05        
query_start: 2015-10-21 14:43:18.309034+05  
state_change: 2015-10-21 14:43:18.309246+05 
waiting: f  
state: idle         
query: SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace
```

Is this normal ? How I have to change my code? Where I have made miskate(mistakes) ?

Comment: Do you use a pooled datasource?

Comment: do you close your `CallableStatment` anywhere?

Comment: @BackSlash yes, Initial and Minimum Pool Size :8 ,Maximum Pool Size: 32. But there are 94 numbackends

Comment: @KevinEsche in there ,  `finally {
                if (callableStatement != null) {
                    try {
                        callableStatement.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HopImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }`